# User Geolocation to Nearest Address Calculations

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, geolocation

I am working on an application where I have some roads in a static vairable (say 7 road names  with their address and geolocation). The user of my application would have GPS enabled device so I can retrieve coordinates as where they are standing.

I have user location in longitude and latitude and also 7 addresses in longitude and latitude. I want to select 1 of those 7 addresses matching each with current user location and I am not sure how should I compare to select the nearest one.

Say if user is on **Armour Road, Peterborough** and as the road is quite long, user can be anywhere at that road resulting in different coordinates. So how can I match user coordinates with that it tells me s/he on Armour Road although no matter where at Armour Road.

How can I check if user is on  Armour Road or some other targeted road?

Comment: If you type this (44.3261361,-78.3099839) in Google Maps, you will see it comes to Armour Rd but not in written name.

Answer (score 1):

You would prob use a circle-distance algorithm to the distance between all coordinates. When you got which one is the nearest you have a really hard problem to solve. If the user is at the road or nearby, if I understood you correctly.

The people at Yelp! solved this problem by acquiring the coordinates of the road. You always have to mind the error in accuracy which brings you to the point of assuming. If you have two possible roads within the same accuracy you are basically always screwed.

Comment: getting coordinates of the road is the first thought I got too but then I am not aligned to too much manual work :(